# Approximating leaky ReLU with a differentiable function

Tags: neural-networks

The ReLU activation function of a neural net can be approximated by the softplus function, which is differentiable. How would you approximate the [leaky ReLU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relu#Leaky_ReLUs) with a differentiable function?

Comment: The function that approximates ReLU is softplus, not softmax.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why do you need a differentiable approximation of leaky ReLU? Its non-differentiability at zero is not an issue in practical applications...

Comment: Continuous first derivative and invertible is here (desmos link).
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/den3cv7agj

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The softplus function is commonly described as a smooth approximation of the standard ReLU:

$$s(x) = \log(1 + e^x)$$

[image]

The leaky ReLU (with leak coefficient $\alpha$) is:

$$r_L(x) = \max \{ \alpha x, x\}$$

We can also write this as:

$$r_L(x) = \alpha x + (1-\alpha) \max\{0, x\}$$

Note that $\max\{0, x\}$ is the standard ReLU. So, we can construct a smooth approximation to the leaky ReLU by substituting in the softplus function:

$$s_L(x) = \alpha x + (1-\alpha) \log(1 + e^x)$$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled on this on accident, not sure if this would be useful but try this weird function I thought of:

(1/20)*x*(e^arctan(x))

Edit: let's put a constant of say (1/20) in front to prevent the slope beign greater than one

arctan goes to plus or minus pi/2 at values |x|>3 so we have on the left hand side x*e^(-pi/2)= x*(small constant) and on the right side x*e^(pi/2) = x*(large constant) which resembles the leaky-relu activation function

plotted on wolfram alpha:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x*%28e%5Earctan%28x%29%29

Comment: A key feature of the relu function is that its derivative is at most 1. This is important because the composition of many relu layers will have gradient at most 1; it will not compound to become very large. Your proposed function appears to have a maximum gradient much larger than 1, implying that the gradient in a deep network is at risk of blowing up.

Comment: Ok, we can solve that by adding a constant lets say (1/20) in front to get a function who's slope isn't bigget than one:         [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot++%281%2F20%29*x*%28e%5E%28arctan%28x%29%29%29+from+-10+to+10+)

Comment: I appreciate the attempt to fix this, but I'm afraid it introduces a new problem. The derivative of the proposed function is always less than 0.25. The composition of many layers using this function will exponentially vanish to zero, so weights very far from the output will not be updated at all. This is sometimes called the "vanishing gradient problem."

Comment: I thought the vanishing gradient problem is when the gradient gradually goes to zero, for example the softplus function ln(1+e^x) where the more negative the function the closer the gradient is to zero. Anyway, we can make the slope close to one by the following constant [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+%281%2F4.8104773809653%29*x*%28e%5Earctan%28x%29%29++from+-10+to+100+)

Comment: where 4.8104773809653 is just e^(pi/2)

Answer (score 1):

Leaky RELU is defined as:

[image]

[LogSumExp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LogSumExp) is a smooth approximation of the *max* function. So I would go with:

[image]